Video Playback in Sequencer still lagging after Proxy Configuration
I was following this tutorial on getting rid of video playback lags with the use of proxies, which I thought worked out pretty well. After configuring the proxies at Proxy Render Size 25% and then selecting all strips and clicking the Rebuild proxy and Timecode Indices button, I successfully built the proxies. I noticed that scrubbing is pretty fast, so I thought I had basically eliminated the lag. Here scrubbing is smooth and fast:

However, when I press the Spacebar to play the video, it still lags. The video strips don't have any modifiers or special edits applied to them. Did I miss anything in the configuration?


Exact same issue here. Did you figure it out?
